# Save "complex" data in database

Tags: database, node.js

I need to store data for an app in node, mostly some simple key:value pairs (username: 'xx'). But parts of it
is a little more complex, e.g. an array of objects.

The amount of objects inside this array changes relativly often and could be different
for every user. So it looks more or less like this:

```
{
    name: 'xx',
    //...
    complexData: [{
        value: 1,
        whatever: 40
    }, {
        value: 2,
        whatever: 11
    }, {
        value: 5,
        whatever: 20
    }]
}
```

What's the best way to store that data? I only worked with MySQL and that could work pretty easy with key:value pairs, but what about the more complex array? Do I have to use a new table for it, which I personally would like to avoid. Or could all of this be done with a different ("easier") database type? I personally don't really like the SQL queries anyway (but if it's the "best" and most performant way to do, I'll still do it).

Comment: Since your data looks to be json-ish, I would suggest at least investigating MongoDB. CouchDB and Couchbase would also be good candidates for this sort of data. But I find those new to the noSQL world find Mongo a very easy DB to learn.

Comment: @bbuckley123 Thanks, MongoDB seems to work. As far as I understood it, I can also save arrays or objects (like the 'complexData' example) as values in MongoDB, right? Just for the sake of completeness: How would I save data like this in a MySQL database?

Comment: Mongo will store your json in a very similar manner to which you insert it. Just read the docs and do some examples and you'll see. Most RDBMS systems -- including mySQL and postgreSQL -- have a JSON datatype. Just use that if you want to stay relational.